# Count chars, remove extra chars and add string before input

Tags: jquery, substring

I would like to be able to count the chars in an element, remove the extra chars if the amount exceeds the limit, and add a string **before** the allowed text.

So far I have this:

```
var ref = "really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_loong_text";
if (ref.length > 47) {
    ref = '...'+ref.substr(0,47);
}
$("#box").text("Ref: "+ref);

<textarea maxlength="50" name="box" rows="6" cols="40" id="box"></textarea>
```

In this case I want the sting to be maximum 47 characters, and the add ... to the beginning of it = 50 chars in total. 
It kind of works, but I would like to cut out the **first part** of the string if it exceeds the limit, not the last part. How do I do that?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v98Rw/3/).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start substring from index `length - 47` to `length`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/v98Rw/7/)**

```
var ref = "really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really_loong_text";
if (ref.length > 50) {
    ref = '...'+ref.substr(ref.length-47,ref.length);
}
$("#box").text("Ref: "+ref);
```

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thanks. But I still need the last 47 characters of the var ref - not the first 47 chars. :-)

Comment: Yes, you got it. Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
var ref = "really_really_really_really_really_really_really_really__loong_text";
if (ref.length > 50) {
  var endStringLength = ref.length-47;
  ref = ref.slice(-endStringLength) + '...';
}
$("#box").text("Ref: "+ref);
```

Comment: Is this solution better, faster, or...?